# Shortest way to print last file modified in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

What is the shortest way in number of characters to write the filename of the latest file modified in the current working directory? I move through log directories all the time and I have to type ls -trlh to view all the files; then copy paste the file name of the last modified file but using the mouse. Then I have to type "less CTRL+V" It's too long. How can I just type 'less $(lastfilemodified)' I might as well do an alias for it, if it's too long. Thanks!

Comment: Using `ls` is the wrong way to get the file in the first place. You might want to consider using `zsh`: `less *(om[1])`.

Comment: The shortest way would be to write a function with a single letter name that does what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use tail -1 to get the last line.

```
less `ls -tr | tail -n1`
```

Comment: `tail -1` isn't guaranteed to work; `tail -n 1` would be safer at the cost of two characters, though the space after `n` might be optional. (And it's probably worth the caveat that this won't work if the most recent file has a newline in its name.)

Comment: `ls -tr | tail -1` is kinda long to type every time so I might have to just do an alias; in that case I will add the -n anyway cause length won't matter anymore

Comment: If `ls` supports the `--group-directories-first` option, using it will give you the newest text file, even if a directory is newer.

Answer (score 1):

Not short, but I think it's robust.

```
less_last() {
    less "$(
        stat --printf='%Y\t%n\0' * | 
        sort -z -k1,1nr | 
        { read -d "" time name; echo "$name"; }
    )"
)
```

Requires GNU tools.

I assume you mean "newest" file when you say "last modified" --> "most recently touched".